# inverse laplace transform of $\frac{e^s}{1 + e^s}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

i need to compute the inverse laplace transform of $\frac{e^s}{1 + e^s}$, but i'm kind of lost.

i know that $\frac{e^s}{1 + e^s} = \frac{1}{1 - e^{-s}}$, so this can be expressed as a geometric series, i.e., $\frac{1}{1 - e^{-s}} = 1 + e^{-s} + e^{-2s} + e^{-3s} + ... + e^{-ks} + ...$.

i also know that the laplace transform of each element of this series expansion is $\delta(t - k)$, i.e., $L(1) + L(e^{-s}) + L(e^{-2s}) + L(e^{-3s}) + ... + L(e^{-ks}) + ... = \delta(t) + \delta(t - 1) + \delta(t - 2) + \delta(t - 3) + ... + \delta(t - k) + ...$.

so this suggests to me that $L(\frac{1}{1 - e^{-s}}) = L(\frac{e^s}{1 + e^s}) = \sum_{i = 0}^k \delta(t - k)$.

and i think this last result implies that $L^{-1}(\sum_{i = 0}^k \delta(t - k)) = \frac{e^s}{1 + e^s}$, but i have also been told that another possible result is $\delta(sin(\pi \cdot x))$.

any advice? thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't $\delta(\sin(\pi x)) u(x)$, where $u(x)$ is the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function)?

Comment: There is some confusion in this question between $L$ and $L^{-1}$.  Do you understand what $\delta(\sin(\pi x))$ or more generally $\delta(f(x))$ means?

Comment: @BrianBorchers, i'm a bit hazy about both

Comment: @EricTowers i only saw the version with sine. there was nothing outside.